# Handle inaccurracy of float

Tags: c++, precision, floating-accuracy, floating-point-conversion

I have a string

```
strValue = "11.900000"
```

I want to parse it to a float value. So I tried:

```
float fValue = -1;
sscanf_s(strValue.c_str(), "%f", &fValue);

try
{
    double test = std::stod(strValue, &sz);
    fValue = (float) std::stod(strValue, &sz);
}
catch (...)
{
    fValue = -1;
}
```

For `double` it is accurate:

```
test = 11.900000000000000
```

For `float` it is inaccurate:

```
fValue = 11.8999996
```

Is there a possibility to do this accurately? (I know there is a inaccuracy while working with floats, but is there a better way to do it?)

Comment: No. There is no way to represent 11.9 as a `float`, as your example illustrates. The underlying value is [binary-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and (most) multiples of 0.1 do not have an exact representation in binary.

Comment: Floating point numbers *are* inaccurate and suffer from scaling errors. Your compiler  may support a `decimal` type but C++ still hasn't standardized decimal support -  it's scheduled for C++17.

Comment: You may be able to use the  [Boost MultiPrecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html) library until decimals are added to C++

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking because it's not clear what you're actually trying to do. You clearly found a more accurate way, using `double`. So why are you asking us how to do something you already figured out how to do? (How accurate do you want it to be exactly? Infinitely accurate?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz even doubles aren't sufficient for financial calculations if there is a chance that you'll get errors in 4 or 5 decimal calculations. That's why other languages have `decimal` types

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: that's not necessarily true... many financial systems use `double` and trust that all the accumulated errors won't reach the level of impacting the least significant digit remaining after rounding to cents/yen/whatever.  With ~15 significant digits, that's often practical even if there're errors *"in 4 or 5 decimal calculations"*.

Comment: @TonyD only if their language doesn't have a decimal type, or they want to trade accuracy for hw-accelerated speed (in which case they use floats or ints). When that fails of course ... google for [Knight Capital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Capital_Group#2012_stock_trading_disruption). There's a difference between accounting where an error in even a single transaction is an issue, and trading of large amounts where errors typically get cancelled out. Eg, a single dollar error is enough for an airline to refuse to issue a ticket bought in another currency

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: *"only if their language"* - only? Even the [C++17 proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3871.html) says *"It isn’t expected that decimal floating points are used for heavy number crunching..."*. *"trade accuracy for hw-accelerated speed (in which case they use floats or ints)"* - nonsense - many financial systems use `double` over `float` because it provides *sufficient* accuracy while `float` doesn't. As someone who's spent the last ~20 years programming for banks & financial data providers, your summary of industry practice doesn't ring true.

Comment: 11.9 can no way be represented exactly in a binary double type. Print it with at least 20 digits of precision and you'll see

Answer (score 2):

The value `11.8999996` is the most precise approximation of `11.9` that can be represented by the `float` type.

Comment: Their `float` type does not represent 11.8999996. That is just what is printed.

Answer (score 2):

It's **not** correct for double or any other binary floating-point types. Just print more digits after the radix point and you'll begin to see "garbage" digits soon

The only way for you is to use a [*decimal* floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) type. If your platform has [`FLT_RADIX == 10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) then you can directly use the built-in `float`, but obviously it's not your case, and I don't know any current system that uses decimal float [except IBM z-series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234616/995714).

So you need a custom type for that. You can use some IEEE-754 decimal32 libraries like [Intel® Decimal Floating-Point Math Library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library/) or [libdfp](https://github.com/libdfp/libdfp). Or if you use gcc then it already has [support for decimal float](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html) via the `_Decimal32` type

You can find more information in this question [How do I use decimal (float) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9316476/995714)